# Text input - can't align text top or bottom, only center

Tags: css

folks! **I'm trying to align the text inside a text form input to be next to the line at the bottom**, but it doesn't quite concede, insisting on being center aligned.

I've put some `vertical-align: bottom` on different elements, but it didn't work (it's on the code below).

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/ironsand-sou-eu/pen/zYEmEdw

HTML:

```
<div class="form-input field">
  <input type="text" name="my_input" id="my_input" value="I'd love to be a little closer to the line below! Can you help me?">
  <label for="my_input" data-title="Just some label"></label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.form-input {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px green solid;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
}

.form-input::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  transition: ease-out 300ms;
}

.form-input:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}

.form-input:focus-within::before {
  width: 100%;
}

.form-input input {
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.form-input input:focus-visible {
  outline: none;
}

.field {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.field label::before {
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 15px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #777;
  transition: 300ms all;
}

.field input {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: green;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Place this at the bottom of the CSS section:

```
input[type=text] {
  height: 15px;
}
```

Comment: This is something (I stayed with 30px, not 15), but I don't want to decrease the input size. Instead, my goal is no align the text to the bottom. Thanks. If I can't get it through, I'm going to use this--but it's a workaround, not an answer.